# Should cookie and session be checked at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

is this scenario I am following correct? my question is at the bottom.I use mvc 4.0 c# thank you

When the user logs in, I encrypt the password and check it in the database. If the password is correct.I create a session in the format USER_ID+Session+Guid, encrypt it and throw it to the server. If the user checked the remember me option, I create a cookie and save the encrypted session both in the cookie and in the database.

**LoginController**

```
      public ActionResult Login(FormCollection form,UserItem user)
    {
       bool REMEMBER= Convert.ToBoolean(form["hdnREMEMBER"]);
        user.PASSWORD = BaseCore.Encrypt(user.PASSWORD.ToString(), true);
        bool remember = user.REMEMBER_ME;
        user = blContext.GetLogin(user.MAIL, user.PASSWORD);
        user.REMEMBER_ME = REMEMBER;
        if (user.USER_ID > 0)
        { 
            user.SESSION = BaseCore.Encrypt(user.USER_ID.ToString() + "#" + Session.SessionID + "#" + Guid.NewGuid(), true);
            if (user.REMEMBER_ME)
            {
                HttpResponseExtension.SetAuthCookie(this.HttpContext, user.USER_ID.ToString(), user.REMEMBER_ME, user.SESSION);
                blContext.AddOrUpdateUser(user);
            }
             
            SessionManager.Save<string>("SystemSession", user.SESSION.ToString());

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
    }
```

if there is session or cookie in login index, I redirect to home page

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SessionManager.Get<string>("SystemSession")) ||
            new SettingController().CheckCookie(this.HttpContext))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

If there is a server session in the home directory, I open the home page directly. If the user has closed the page or the session has timed out, I go to the second if block and check for a cookie. Here I decrypt the cookie and get the USER_ID and the user's information from the database. I compare cookieSession with the session in the database and if they are equal, I assign the same sessionID back to the server session.

**homeController**

```
     public ActionResult Index()
    {     
        UserItem userItem = new UserItem();

        var serverSession = SessionManager.Get<string>("SystemSession");
        var cookiSession = new SettingController().GetCookie(this.HttpContext);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serverSession))
        {

            return View();
        }

        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookiSession))
        {
            cookiSession = BaseCore.Decrypt(cookiSession, true);
            string userID = cookiSession.Split('#')[0]; 
            userItem = new UserBL().GetUser(int.Parse(userID));
            serverSession = BaseCore.Decrypt(userItem.SESSION, true);

            if (cookiSession == serverSession)
            {
                SessionManager.Save<string>("SystemSession", userItem.SESSION.ToString());
                return View();
            }
        }

        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
        Session.RemoveAll();
        HttpResponseExtension.SetAuthCookie(this.HttpContext, null, false, null);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");

    }
```

**RouteConfig**

```
    public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new string[] { "Project.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

1 ) I could do that instead of doing two if blocks in homeIndex, but then it would have to go to the database in vain if there is a session on the server. However, do I need to check the database in serverSession? Since the session inside the server is hidden, it won't be visible on the client side anyway.

2. If I am going to check it from the ServerSession database, I need to delete the session_id from the database as soon as the user closes the page. Global.asax has session_end, but this works when the session times out. There is no way to capture it when the page is closed. Or what should I do ?

   ```
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serverSession) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookiSession))
        {
            cookiSession = BaseCore.Decrypt(cookiSession, true);
            string userID = cookiSession.Split('#')[0];
            userItem = new UserBL().GetUser(int.Parse(userID));
            serverSession = BaseCore.Decrypt(userItem.SESSION, true);

            if (cookiSession == serverSession)
            {
                SessionManager.Save<string>("SystemSession", userItem.SESSION.ToString());

            }
            return View();
        }
   ```

Comment: Why aren't you using Identity for this? It gives you sooo much of this (and loads more) out of the box, and has been extensively tested by Microsoft's engineers. Why reinvent the wheel?